# Class 'OwnerService' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So i want to get instance of a given class, this is my code :

```
class OwnerServiceFactory
{
    protected static $instance;
    protected static $provider;

    public function __construct($provider = 'xxx')
    {
        static::$provider = $provider;
    }

    final public static function getInstance()
    {
        $class = ucfirst(static::$provider)."OwnerService";

        if(!static::$instance) static::$instance = new $class();

        return static::$instance;
    }
}
```

OwnerService and OwnerServiceFactory classes are already in the same namespace.
the problem is in this line `if(!static::$instance) static::$instance = new $class();`

when i tried my code i got **Class 'OwnerService' not found** and when i change `new $class();` by new OwnerService() it work fine.

Comment: What error did you get for this?

Comment: when i tried my code i got Class 'OwnerService' not found and when i change new $class(); by new OwnerService() it work fine.

Comment: If both `OwnerService` and `OwnerServiceFactory` are in the same namespace, you can get `OwnerServiceFacoty` namespace and prepend it to the `OwnerService` while assigning it to the `$class` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$class` needs to contain the fully qualified class name to instantiate from a string.  You say these classes are in a namespace? So `$class` will need to include that namespace, right now I'm assuming its just `OwnerService`, which PHP thinks is living in the root namespace `\OwnerService`.

Comment: the $class must pass dynamically  using this ucfirst(static::$provider)."OwnerService", how can i instantiate from a string ?

Comment: @Mohammadov You'll need to dynamically provide the class namespace as well.

Comment: i tried to add this : use \OwnerService but i got the same error

Comment: try `$class = __NAMESPACE__. '\\' . ucfirst(static::$provider)."OwnerService";`